# How do I animate tiled sprite after contact? AndEngine

Tags: java, android, animation, andengine, contacts

I am trying to animate one of my TiledSprites after the player makes contact with the sprite. Here is my code so far:

```
levelObject = new AnimatedSprite(x, y, resourceManager.wooden_crate_region, vbom)
                {
                    @Override
                    protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) 
                    {
                        super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

                        if (player.collidesWith(this))
                        {
                            addToScore(1);
                            final long[] CRATE_ANIMATE = new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 10000};
                            this.animate(CRATE_ANIMATE, 0, 3, true);
                            this.setIgnoreUpdate(true);
                        }
                    }
                };
```

But when I try to play the game, the player makes contact and goes through the sprite. Not sure whats going on. It does add the score, but no animation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the line

```
this.setIgnoreUpdate(true);
```

this line ignores any update on your object, means it won't animate it either.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. But I do know that if I remove this, the score will keep going up while the two are touching. Is there away i Can animate the sprite on contact, add to the score, and then disable updates? Sorry still new to AndEngine and wrapping my head around it all.